# getting error <Follower: Follower object (None)> instance isn't saved. Use bulk=False or save the object first

Tags: django, django-models, manage.py

I am trying to create a follow functionality in django. I am using the following model. I would like to test that this works on django manage.py shell. When I do the relevant imports and run

```
user1.following.add(Follower(following=user2))
```

I get the following error

> <Follower: Follower object (None)> instance isn't saved.
>   Use bulk=False or save the object first.

what is the reason for this?

models.py

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='following',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='followers',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('follower', 'following')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s follows %s' % (self.follower, self.following)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you were expecting to happen. As the error says, you haven't saved that Follower object.

But that doesn't seem to be the right way to do it, anyway. I *think* you just want to create a Follower object with both users:

```
Follower.objects.create(follower=user1, following=user2)
```

which directly adds it on both sides.

Even better, remove your Follower model completely and declare a ManyToMany relationship on User back to "self", with symmetrical=False.

Comment: so how do I save the follower object

Comment: You just haven’t explained very well what you have done .

Comment: Which isn’t explained . It’s important to explain what you have done . Otherwise no one can learn from this.

Comment: No, I explained exactly what I did; I said you needed to create a follower object, and posted the code to do so. It is completely obscure to me what other explanation you think you need.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory, you have to use **bulk=False** while adding a **Follower** object.

```
user1.following.add(Follower(following=user2),bulk=False)
```

The reason is that you are creating a single record in the ManyToMany (i.e Follower) model.